# Upload image from wordpress site to facebook

Tags: facebook, image, wordpress, upload, visitors

I'm using latest version of Wordpress, and NextGen Gallery. I want to allow visitors to upload images on their facebook account from my website. I'm managing a photo blog. I want to give a link **Upload to Facebook** below every image. I tried to learn `facebook_upload_photo` api, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need to get the permissions to post to a user's facebook account. In particular the "publish_stream" permission
2. Follow the instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

Comment: I'd already read that. But i didn't get that how to use it with Wordpress+NG Galleries.